# Spring Reactive test doesn't result in an expected error

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito, project-reactor

I am writing unit tests for one of our reactive methods. This method depends on another service. I have mocked this service. While running the test, i am getting the below error:
`java.lang.AssertionError: expectation "expectError(Class)" failed (expected: onError(MyException); actual: onComplete())`.
Here is what I have tried:
**Method(ReactiveService.class):**

```
@Autowired
private Service serice;

public Mono<MyObject> save(List<MyObject> arg1, String arg2) {
    return SomeUtil.user()
            .map(user -> service.save(arg1, arg2, user))
            .subscribeOn(scheduler)
            .doOnError(e -> {
                throw new MyException(MyObject.class, "save object", e);
            });
}
```

**Test:**

```
@Mock
Service service;

@InjectMocks
ReactiveService reactiveService;

@Test
public void unit_test(){
    when(service.save(any(), any(), any())).thenThrow(new RuntimeException());
    Mono<MyObject> result = reactiveService.save(arg1, arg2);
    StepVerifier.create(result)
        .expectError(MyException.class)
        .verify();
}
```

From the error I understood that, no signal is received from the method. But I am not getting what I have missed here.

Comment: What have you done to resolve it? What have you analyzed? What were the results? What exactly is not clear?

Comment: @mentallurg The previous version of code was having `Mono.defer()` where the junit worked fine. Now after adding the `user` and `map` function it is not working. I suspect that the mocked method is not getting invoked during execution.

Comment: You can easily check, if the mocked method is invocked: call it in the method save() directly. Then you will see if there is an exception. After check you can remove it again.

Comment: your service name is `serice`

Comment: @Rozart Its correct only. I am testing `ReactiveService` class which depends on `Service` class. So i have mocked `Service` class. I am suspecting the `Mono.map()` method, will mock methods get invoked from `map`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the issue you have is caused by `SomeUtil.user()` not emitting a value.

Why do I think it's the case: I have tried out a simple example to reproduce your issue:

```java
    @Test
    void test() {
        Mono<String> monoWithContent =
            Mono.just("Content")
            .map(element -> exceptionThrower());

        // TEST 1
        StepVerifier.create(monoWithContent)
            .expectError()
            .verify();

        Mono<String> monoWithoutContent =
            Mono.empty()
            .map(element -> exceptionThrower());

        // TEST 2
        StepVerifier.create(monoWithoutContent)
            .expectError()
            .verify();
    }

    String exceptionThrower() {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
```

The result is :

**TEST 1** - passes successfully, because the value is emitted from `Mono` and it is mapped to an exception (the `RuntimeException` thrown by the `exceptionThrower()`.

**TEST 2** - fails, because there is no value to be emitted from `Mono`, so the `map` method is not invoked and the whole execution finishes without an error.

So to summarize, if there is no content emitted from the `Publisher`, then the transformation operations are not invoked.

Comment: Got it! So I need to mock `SomeUtil.user()` as well to emit some value.

Comment: Yes sure. Actually I am executing the tests now. The issue I am facing is `SomeUtil.user()` is a static method which i am not able to mock using mockito.

Comment: This is a different topic. But in general you should either use PowerMock ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/21116014/1506009 )  or better, refactor your code not to use a static method in this context.